# Google Maps stuck on Registering

Tags: android, google-maps

I have Android app that used to work fine..

I just upgraded to Android Studio 2.2, since then I am getting Google Maps stuck on Registering!

[image]

Is it an issue with 2.2 or do I have to change code for this upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the API version/key?

Comment: No, nothing changed